# Rotation of Graphics3D like rotating Plot3D

Tags: graphics3d

I like the way 3D plots are rotated with the z-axis always pointing up-down. 
Is there an elegant way of forcing that type of rotation on Graphics3D?

I have tried the following:

1. Using an invisible locator and mapping the position to a specific viewpoint. That works, but behaves strangely (from the users perspective) because the graphics rotates as soon as the mouse is clicked and not the 'click-drag'-way, that you would expect, due to the locator jumping.
2. Using 'Show' to combine the Graphics3D with a Plot3D. Then the rotation is exactly as I would like, but it slows the animation due to the (undesired) surface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The option `Method` offers a way to control the rotation.

Test the following idea:

```
Graphics3D[Cone[], Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}]
```